# Delay check on if widget exists

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I've been giving myself a headache trying to work with Nuke's docked panels. It works with `QStackedWidgets` as tabs, where the entire program is built out of it and is very dynamic.

Just for the record I've been dealing with stuff like this, it works but takes a ton of trial and error to figure out:

```
def x(self):
    return self.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().x()
def y(self):
    return self.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().y()
def closeEvent(self, event):
    is_docked = self.x() == self.y() == 0
    num_tabs = widget.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().count()

    #Delete the window
    if not is_docked and num_tabs == 1:
        self.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().close()

    #Delete the tab
    else:
        for obj in QtWidgets.QApplication.allWidgets():
            if obj.objectName() == 'uk.co.thefoundry.NukeTestWindow':
                 obj.deleteLater()
    event.accept()
```

I've attempted to get full control so I can deal with callbacks at a later time, which has been a little hard as it never calls `closeEvent`. I can currently handle automatically closing it, and I'll be using `hideEvent` to read the window position, as it calls just before it closes.

I have got *almost* all the functionality I need, but I'm still not able to catch when a user manually closes the tab. I've figured out technically how to detect if it's closed, but it only works *after* the function has finished.

If I print out the value of `self.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()`, it says it is a widget, but if I print after the code has executed, then it equals `None`, so that is the level of parents to ideally check.

How do I query that in `hideEvent` but offset the execution until after everything has finished? As far as I'm aware there's no other events being called after, I've considered threading with `time.sleep`, but it's not very clean and would be prone to issues.

Maya had a command called `evalDeferred` which was quite useful in cases like this. I just had a quick test with `nukescripts.utils.executeDeferred` but even with sleeping for a second it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can delay a method by x ms by using QTimer::singleShot.

For example: 
`QTimer::singleShot(50, this, &MyWidget::mySlot) ;` will execute slot mySlot 50ms after the call to this instuction. It is equivalent to making a QTimer, and connecting its end event with said slot.
Also don't forget mySlot can calls himself like this if you want.

```
void MyWidget::mySlot() {
     if(conditionOK) {
         // Do stuff
     }
     else {
         // Try again 50ms later
          QTimer::singleShot(50, this, &MyWidget::mySlot) ;
     }
}
```

Be careful with it, as you have no garantee as to what can happens during those 50ms. So it's not an "execute as soon as something" kind of deal. Also be careful avoiding infinite recursion.
Hope it helps.

Edit: You can also provide the arguments, by the way:

```
QTimer::singleShot(50, this, [=](){mySlot(arguments) ;}) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently trying an alternative way (delete and recreate all callbacks on the hide/showEvent, a little cleaner but more processing needed), don't think I'll finish before heading home for the weekend though so if it doesn't work I'll be trying this early next week :)